# Where can I find the "Interesting" tab?

Tags: support, interesting-page

When I clicked on the Questions button, it showed a new tab named *interesting* with a list of questions. But I then couldn't locate it again.

Is it possible to get the list of interesting questions?

Comment: Go the the homepage: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: To easily go to the homepage, click on the logo at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) you will find at home page

[image]

Comment: thank u it is there:)